# Combobox image background overlap

Tags: html, css, background, combobox, overlay

So, i have a combobox with fixed `witdh` and a `background` image to make a custom arrow.

I want to limit the number of characters shown so it doesn't overlap the `background` image.

Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zagzH/314/)  of what's happening and what i want to do.

@Edit
I tested this and it as far as i know in IE this problem doesn't happen. I don't know if it's only because i'm using google chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your select {} definition:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100px;
margin-right: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zagzH/316/